# Surface: intersection of 2 polar curves

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, surfaces

I have these two polar curves:

$$
C_1: r = 2 - \cos(\theta)\\
C_2: r = 3 \cos(\theta)
$$

Plots: [C1 and C2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r+%3D+2+-+cos%28theta%29%2C+r+%3D+3%2acos%28theta%29).

I need to find the surface of $D = C_1 \cap C_2$.

I started by finding the solution to $C_1 = C_2$. I found $\pm \pi\over{3}$.

I tried this integral:

$$
\int_{-\pi\over{3}}^{\pi\over{3}} \int_{3\cos(\theta)}^{2-\cos(\theta)} r \;\operatorname d\!r \operatorname d\!\theta
$$

However, I'm not sure about that $r$, and I get a negative answer.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $-\frac{\pi}{3} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{3}$, we have $3\cos \theta \ge 2-\cos\theta$, and so, your integral yields a negative value.

Draw both graphs on the same region. You'll see that $\theta$ can range from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

If $0 \le |\theta| \le \frac{\pi}{3}$, and the point $(r,\theta)$ is in $D$, then we must have $0 \le r \le 2-\cos \theta$.

If $\frac{\pi}{3} \le |\theta| \le \frac{\pi}{2}$, and the point $(r,\theta)$ is in $D$, then we must have $0 \le r \le 3\cos \theta$.

So, the area should be $\displaystyle 2\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\int_{0}^{2-\cos\theta}r\,dr\,d\theta + 2\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{3\cos\theta}r\,dr\,d\theta$.

Note: I have exploited symmetry about the $x$-axis, which is why I only integrated over $0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and multiplied the result by $2$.

Comment: I didn't think I could separate the two. I thought I had to do one minus the other on an interval.
But this confirms what I was thinking, because the intervals aren't "synchronised," if you see what I mean.

I'll try this out!

Comment: I think I understand it. You basically did [this](http://i.imgur.com/LYCCE9j.jpg), right? (Sorry for the bad picture.)

Comment: That picture is extremely blurry, but it looks like you have the correct idea.

Comment: Yeah sorry again for the picture! I just did it, and the answer makes sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because the angular interval over which you want to integrate the area between the two curves does not correspond for each curve.  This is because the curve $r = 3 \cos \theta$ is traversed *twice* when $r = 2 - \cos \theta$ is traversed only once for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$:[image]

To rectify this, we would use the method shown in JimmK4542's answer:  over $\theta \in [0,\pi/3]$, we integrate the sector traced by the blue curve, and then from $\theta \in [\pi/3, \pi/2]$, we integrate the slice traced by the red curve.  However, you can "rescue" your calculation by computing the negative area as you did, and then simply add the area of the red circle:  $$A = \pi \bigl(\tfrac{3}{2}\bigr)^2 + \int_{\theta = -\pi/3}^{\pi/3} \int_{r = 3 \cos \theta}^{2 - \cos \theta} r \, dr \, d\theta.$$

Comment: The fact that the curve $r = 3\cos \theta$ is traversed twice over $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ is not the problem here. The OP's integral was calculating the negative of the area inside $r = 3\cos \theta$ and outside $r = 2-\cos\theta$ as opposed to the area inside both curves.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more clear to point that out.